# Random function of random variable

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$ be a probability space. Suppose that $\phi:(\Omega,\mathbb{R})\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is such that $\phi(\omega,\cdot)$ and $\phi(\cdot,x)$ are Borel measurable. Finally let $X:\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a random variable. I am interested in the measurability of $\phi(\cdot,X(\cdot)):\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$. I have been trying to find an example of $\phi$ where the result is not measurable.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take $\Omega = [0,1]$ with $\mathcal{F}$ the Lebesgue (or Borel) measurable sets and $\mathbb{P}$ Lebesgue measure.  Let $E \subset [0,1]$ be your favorite non-Lebesgue measurable set.  Define $\phi : [0,1] \times \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ by $$\phi(x,y) = \begin{cases} 1, &  x=y \in E \\ 0, & \text{otherwise.}\end{cases}$$
Then for each $x$, $\phi(x, \cdot)$ is either $0$ or $1_{\{x\}}$, which in either case is Borel.  Similarly, $\phi(\cdot, y)$ is either $0$ or $1_{\{y\}}$.

Now let $X : \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ simply be $X(x) = x$ (which is a random variable with a $U(0,1)$ distribution).  Then $\phi(x, X(x)) = \phi(x,x) = 1_E(x)$ which is not measurable.

Comment: Thank you very much. Very clear answer.